# Heat equation Dirichlet Boundary Conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $\Omega \subset R^n$ be a bounded domain with piecewise 
$C^1$ boundary. Suppose that
$u(t, x)$ is real-valued and satisfies the heat equation:

$$\frac{∂u}{∂t} − Δu = 0 $$

on $(0,∞) \times \Omega$.

Define
$$\eta(t) :=∫_Ωu^2(t, x) d^n x $$

(a) Assume that $u$ satisfies the Dirichlet boundary conditions:

$$u(t, x)|_{x∈∂Ω} = 0$$

for $t ≥ 0$. Show that $\eta$ decreases as a function of $t$.

(b) Use (a) to show that a solution $u$ satisfying boundary and initial conditions

$$u|_{t=0} = g $$ $$ u|_{x∈∂Ω} = h$$

for some continuous functions $g$ on $\Omega$ and $h$ on $\partial \Omega$, is uniquely determined by $g$ and $h$.

Need help answering this. I understand for (a) to show that $\eta$ is decreasing we need to show the derivative is strictly less than zero. Unsure how to prove this I have seen people use Gauss's theorem to show. 
(b) I am unsure how to show it is unique. Also have had the hint to let $w = u-v$, where $u$ and $v$ are solutions to the heat equation. Then to show that $w$ is always zero, thus $u = v$ but I am not sure where to begin.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Part A, differentiate with respect to $t$, use the PDE and integrate by parts. Part B, $w = u-v$ solves $\partial_{t} w = \Delta w$ with $w \lvert_{x \in \partial \Omega} = 0, w \lvert_{t = 0} = 0$.

Comment: @mattos That is (a hint for) an answer not a comment, please write it up as such.

Comment: I think I get part B but I am still confused with part A could you please go into more detail about how to integrate it and why this gives the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With

$u_t = \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \nabla^2 u = \nabla \cdot \nabla u \tag 1$

and

$\eta(t) = \displaystyle \int_\Omega u^2(x, t) \; d^nx, \tag 2$

we have

$\eta_t(t) = \dfrac{d\eta(t)}{dt} = 2\displaystyle \int_\Omega u(x, t) u_t(x, t) \; d^n x; \tag 3$

consider the integral on the right of (3); by virtue of (1),

$\displaystyle \int_\Omega u(x, t) u_t(x, t) \; d^n x = \int_\Omega u(x, t) \nabla \cdot \nabla u(x, t) \; d^n x; \tag 4$

now,

$\nabla \cdot (u \nabla u) = \nabla u \cdot \nabla u + u \nabla \cdot \nabla u, \tag 5$

from which

$u \nabla \cdot \nabla u  = \nabla \cdot (u\nabla u) - \nabla u \cdot \nabla u, \tag 6$

and hence

$\displaystyle\int_\Omega u\nabla \cdot \nabla u \; d^n x = \int _\Omega  \nabla \cdot (u\nabla u) \;  d^nx - \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla u,     \tag 7$

where we temporarily suppressed the $x, t$ arguments of $u$ for the sake of notational convenience; now the first integral on the right may be written

$ \displaystyle \int _\Omega  \nabla \cdot (u\nabla u) \;  d^nx = \int_{\partial \Omega} u \nabla u \cdot \mathbf n \; dS,  \tag 8$

where $\mathbf n$ is the outward-pointing unit normal field to, and $dS$ is the volume element on, $\partial \Omega$;  we are given that

$u(x, t) \vert_{x \in \partial \Omega} = 0, \tag 9$

whence

$\displaystyle  \int_{\partial \Omega} u(x, t) \nabla u(x, t) \cdot \mathbf n \; dS = 0; \tag{10}$

continuing in this direction we apply (8)-(10) to (7) and thus find

$\displaystyle \int_\Omega  u\nabla \cdot \nabla u \; d^n x =  - \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla u;     \tag{11}$

working our way back to (3):

$\eta_t(t) = \dfrac{d\eta(t)}{dt} = -2\displaystyle \int_\Omega \nabla u(x, t) \cdot \nabla u(x, t)\; d^n x < 0; \tag{12}$

that is, $\eta(t)$ decreases with increasing $t$, provided $u(x, t)$ is not constant on $\Omega$.  Since $u(x, t)$ obeys the Dirichlet boundary condition (9), it is constant on $\Omega$ precisely when it vanishes there; thus we conclude $\eta(t)$ will decrease as long as $u(x, t) \ne 0$ on $\Omega$.

We have, I believe, adequately addressed part (a); as for (b), 
we assume with our OP Total-fury the existence of distinct solutions $u$ and $v$ which share the same boundary and initial conditions:

$u \mid_{t = 0} = v \mid_{t = 0} = g, \tag{13}$

$u \mid_{x \in \Omega} = v \mid_{x \in \Omega} = h; \tag{14}$

we set

$w = u - v; \tag{15}$

then in accord with (13)-(15),

$w \mid_{t = 0} = 0, \tag{16}$

$w \mid_{x \in \Omega} = 0.  \tag{17}$

Now $w$ satisfies the same boundary condition (9) as was stipulated for $u(x, t)$; thus the results of part (a) apply to $w$ and allow us to write

$\eta_t = \dfrac{d\eta}{dt} = \dfrac{d}{dt} \displaystyle \int_{\Omega} w^2(x, t) \; d^n x \le 0, \tag{18}$

with equality holding precisely when $w \equiv 0$ on $\Omega$; it follows then that $w(x, t)$ cannot take any 
non-zero values for $t \ge 0$, since in such event

$\eta(t) = \displaystyle \int_\Omega w^2(x, t) \; d^nx > 0; \tag{19}$

but this is precluded by virtue of (18).  We thus affirm that

$w(x, t) = 0, \tag{20}$

and hence

$u(x, t) = v(x, t); \tag{21}$

the solutions of (1) with the given boundary/initial conditions are thus unique.